# Atom Editor - multiple selections to rename variables quickly doesn't recognize scope

Tags: atom-editor

Sublime text has a feature that allows you to highlight multiple identical selections to rename variables quickly. It is initiated with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on your keyboard. Most importantly it *is* context aware. If I want to rename the variable `is` to `xy`, it won't, for instance, rename `this` to `thxy`.

How do I get Atom to recognize scope? If I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> the same as in Sublime it does not differentiate between is and th**is**.

Highlight the first two letters in this code chunk below (ie 'is') and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. It's jumps to the 'is' in th**is**.

```
is
this is really cool
code
this is really cool
code
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My answer is valid for JavaScript, for which I had the same question as you did.

I installed two more packages in atom:

- https://atom.io/packages/refactor
- https://atom.io/packages/js-refactor

The first one is the core package i think and the second one is javascript-specific. It worked after installing and restarting atom one time.

**For you this package alone should do: https://atom.io/packages/cpp-refactor**